# Page last updated x time ago in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Right now I am using livestamp.js and moment.js to show the page updated/refreshed last x time ago. But is it possible to achieve the same in plain js without the use of other js libraries.

[image]

Comment: Anything that is possible with a JS library is possible with plain JS. The library, after all, is written in JS. Did you research?

Comment: Why can't you simply type `javascript:alert(document.lastModified)` in your browser's address bar?

Comment: I want to use that in my application just the line as show above in my webpage. And I guess this gives me the time and date but I want the time passed in seconds/minutes/hours since the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var renderDate = new Date();
setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = timeSince(renderDate);
}, 5000);

function timeSince(renderDate) {
  var seconds = Math.floor((new Date() - renderDate) / 1000);

  var interval = Math.floor(seconds / 31536000);
  if (interval > 1) {
    return interval + " years ago";
  }
  interval = Math.floor(seconds / 2592000);
  if (interval > 1) {
    return interval + " months ago";
  }
  interval = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
  if (interval > 1) {
    return interval + " days ago";
  }
  interval = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
  if (interval > 1) {
    return interval + " hours ago";
  }
  interval = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
  if (interval >= 1) {
    return interval + " minutes ago";
  }
  return seconds + " seconds ago";
}
```

```html
<div> This page was updated <span id="time">just now</span>.</div>
```